# How to return a map object from template in Helm function?

Tags: go, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I have a function that I want to call in another function. I want it to return a map, but instead it returns the `toString` representation of the map. It **is** an actual map inside the function, but not outside it.

```golang
{{- define "app.getSubKey" -}}
  {{- $name := .source }}
  {{- range $key, $value := .keys }}
    {{- if kindIs "int" $value }}
      {{- $name = index $name (int $value) }}
    {{- else }}
      {{- $name = index $name $value }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- if kindIs "string" $name }}
    {{- trim $name }}
  {{- else }}
    {{ $name }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

When I call this function on the below YAML with `{{- include "app.getSubKey" (dict "source" .Values.vars "keys" (list 0)) }}`, inside the function `$name` is a map (I used `kindOf` to check this) but outside it's of kind string. How can I get it returned as a map?

```yaml
vars:
  - name: something
    value: blah
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be precise: your `app.getSubKey` is not a function, it is a [named template](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/) and as such, it does not return anything. On the other hand, `include` is a function. It takes as arguments a template name and its context, and returns rendered template as a string. You cannot change the type of the `include` function return value.

Said that, I see two options:

- if your goal is to get a properly formatted YAML from the `include "app.getSubKey"` call (still as a string) use toYaml function inside the named template, i.e.:

```yaml
{{- define "app.getSubKey" -}}
  ...
  {{- else }}
    {{- $name | toYaml | nindent 0 }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

> `nindent 0` is necessary to get a properly left align YAML

- if you want to get an actual dictionary (for further processing), you need to convert the string returned from the `include` call back to an object (the `toYaml` in the named template is still required):

```yaml
  {{- $d := dict "source" .Values.vars "keys" (list 0) | include "app.getSubKey" | fromYaml -}}
```

> The function **fromYaml** is undocumented, so using it might be a bit risky. The only trace of it I found in the official docs is in the examples on the [library charts](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/library_charts/#helm) page.

> BTW, the `app.getSubKey` logic doesn't seem correct: it will fail for the `keys` list with more then one element.

---

If `app.getSubKey` returns an array, you must use `fromYamlArray` to "decode" the data.

Comment: Thank you. Why do you say that `app.getSubKey` will fail with more than one element?

Comment: This answer helped me. Just wanted to point out that fromYaml is actually documented https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/